# How to convert blob to MP3 in javascript?

Tags: javascript, audio, mp3, blob

I have blob in my DB.

I want to convert the blob to MP 3.

How i can do it in JavaScript?

Comment: why not store the mp3 file in folder and address in database.

Comment: it was not possible to keep it in mp3

Comment: see this link it may help http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Scripting/PHP/Q_25562011.html.

Comment: can't get the answer of the ticket

Comment: http://audior.ec/blog/recording-mp3-using-only-html5-and-javascript-recordmp3-js/